# No such module 'Combine' when used in my Swift Package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

When I create a swift package, and then I  use the simple line:

```
import Combine
```

I get the following error:

```
No such module 'Combine'
```

I've switched my scheme to `Any iOS Device`

[image]

I also set the platform in the `Package.swift` file

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "AsyncImageView",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v8)],
    products: [
```

It still does not accept Combine.

Comment: Is it about Apple's reactive programming framework?

Comment: Yes, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine

Comment: Okay.  So how do you go from using Combine to creating a Swift page?

Comment: I want to use Combine within the Sources folder of a [Swift Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages) I am creating.

Comment: You are not providing enough detail to reproduce. I can say `import Combine` in a Swift Package, so you need to say enough to explain why you can't.

Comment: Thank you @matt.  My question was: "Why can't I" though.  If I could have filled in that answer I wouldn't have had the impetus to pose the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine is iOS 13 and/or macOS 10.15 or later, only. You need to guarantee the compiler and linker of that condition. Change your package to include

```
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v13), .macOS(.v10_15)
],
```

Now build the package scheme, then build the project scheme, and you're all set.

Comment: " Combine is also available on Mac 10.15 if you want that as well" -@matt